# Fuel system question

Tags: fuel-consumption, fuel-tank, fuel-injection, fuel-additives

[image]

See red arrow in the image. I place fuel additive in my car, all of the additives went into that pipe (in the red arrow image) because i didnt know how to place it. Will it still work? or just a waste?

Comment: What is the year/make/model/engine of the car?

Comment: That looks like the overflow pipe. If so, yeah, the additive's wasted

Comment: Zaid - I think it's the return pipe, not an overflow, so Handy Howie is right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That pipe probably goes to the tank too, it is just there to let air out of the tank while adding fuel down the main pipe.  I believe that your additive will be in the fuel.

Comment: Thanks for answering. My car is Hyundai Accent 2014 1.4L MT. Thank you again. But are you sure? Because it cost me a lot for that additive. God bless you sir!

Comment: I am sure, unless you saw the additive dripping to the ground.